# Legend labels not appearing

Tags: makie.jl

I am attempting to do some line plots using `Makie.jl` but the legend doesnt appear when I pass a value to the `label` argument. Any idea why?

```
using GLMakie: lines, lines!

p,ax, l = lines(
    rand(10),
    label = "label 1"
)

lines!(
    rand(10),
    label = "label 2"
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this: `axislegend(ax)`